# present custom alert above another custom alert or uialertview

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

What it is possible to present custom alert above another custom alert or uialertview? 
e.g I have my custom alert view and i want to present another custom view top of presented custom alert when user click 'OK' button on presented alert the first alert not dismiss and another/second alert show on above on first alert view.
If it is possible the please give me the solution

Comment: While it may indeed be possible you should avoid it as it is bad UI design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't do it. From the Apple documentation: "People know that alerts notify them about problems and dangerous situations." So, you should minimize them.
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/alerts/

It is a intuitive behavior that alert should dismiss after pressing button. So don't change it.

By the way, in which situation you need two alerts one after another? Maybe we can help you with changing logic.